# How to re size different pixel sizes and scale factors?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo

[image]

A client asks me do deliver the files of the logo I made for him. but I really have no idea how sizes and scale factor works in illustrator. can somebody please help me. the attached image are his requests.

Comment: That's a confusing and mostly useless table.

Comment: Since the table uses the phrase **base size** I would guess that the client is requesting 8 sizes of each logo version, where 100% = the base size quoted. Yes, this means that the 150square logo would be identical to the 50square@300% (assuming "store logo"="square logo") .

Answer (score 1):

You change the dimensions of the artboard for every size

Then Save > Save for Web and there you can can change the dimensions lossless 
[image]

Comment: thanks Eli, I tried that same thing. for 50x50 and have 100% but when I tried another size, 70x70 I still got 100% instead of having 140% that I needed..

Comment: @Justine KwanGood If your document is now 70x70 which is the correct enlargement dimensions. Does it matter that the percent didn't go up? However if you change either or of the values, they both should change either way you go.

Comment: I am curious. As Eli stated if the pixel dimensions change to reflect a 140% scale, when applied it will then be 100% of the the new size (always). Am I missing something ?